# Google Sheets. How to get the real range size in pixels

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script converts the selected range into an image, [please see](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNQ6iCMoBCQgJzBB63ymtBQ6BedXZFhjgZZKGItjeVA/copy). It first creates a public PDF URL and then converts it to PNG.

[image]

It works well for small ranges (10-20 rows) and creates a shot including images, charts, sparklines, and formatting.

The problem is with big ranges (100-1000 rows). They contain a border of unknown size and I cannot calculate it.

[image]

Heavy borders make rows higher so the image does not fit.

[image]

If we have no borders or thin borders, the real image size appears a bit smaller than calculated. This creates an empty space below the image.

My code sample for getting the range size in pixels:

```
  // get row height in pixels
  var h = 0;
  for (var i = rownum; i <= rownum2; i++) {
    if (i <= options.measure_limit) {
      size = sheet.getRowHeight(i);
    }
    h += size
    /** manual correction */
    if (size === 2) {
      h-=1;
    } else {
      // h -= 0.42; /** TODO → test the range to make it fit any range */
    }
    
    if ((i % 50) === 0 &&  i <= options.measure_limit) {
      file.toast(
        'Done ' + i + ' rows of ' + rownum2,
        '↕Measuring height...');
    }
  }
  if (i > options.measure_limit) {
    file.toast(
      'Estimation: all other rows are the same size',
      '↕Measuring height...');
  }
```

As you see, I have to loop over all rows which is extremely inefficient. I'd be glad to hear your ideas for code optimization. Now it loops the first 150 rows and next it assumes all other rows have the same height.

## Sample Situations

"Small" ranges are that you can see on screen. "Big" ranges have 100+ rows so they do not fit normal screen. As I create screenshots, I tested all possible range sizes.

**Case1 - no borders or thin borders**

If I select a big range I get the image, and see it has a white space at the bottom. This means the real size of image was slightly smaller than one I get from the Script by calling `sheet.getRowHeight(i)`.

**Case1 - heavy borders**

If I select a big range I get the image, and see not all rows I've selected are on that image. Some rows at the bottom of the range are missing. This means when I add heavy borders, the real size of rows is bigger than one I get from the Script by calling `sheet.getRowHeight(i)`.

## Conclusion

I'd be glad to hear any ideas including JavaScript hacks to remove empty space below the image. If it is currently not possible, please also answer with links to docs.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situation or value you expect? And, can I ask you about the difference between "small ranges" and "big ranges"?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for your response! I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I've added a section called # Sample Situations in my question. Please feel free to ask for any additional details.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I thought that I could correctly understand your question. In my experience, when the border is used for the cells, it seems that the row height + the border size is different from the exported result. I had thought that this might be a bug on the Google side. For example, in this case, how about creating the correction value by creating several exported images by several border sizes? But, I'm worried that whether this value is changed in the future update.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I've tried with a correction, but could not find the rigth value. The idea sounds good to me, I'll have to spend more time on the research.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I'm worried that the pixel size might not be changed linearly with the value of row height and border size. So, in this case, I thought that statistical data might be required to be obtained. About this, I would like to support you. Because I think that when your issue was resolved, it will be useful for you and also other users.

Comment: I apologize that I have still no clear answer to your question. When I tested the cell size including the borders, I thought that the tendency 
 of change of size might be different between height and width. In your situation, how about this? And, for example, when the row height is the default (21 from `getRowHeight`) and the text font size in the cell is increased, the value retrieved by `getRowHeight` is not changed from 21. In this case, is the font size required to be considered?

Comment: Hi @ Tanaike! Thank you very much for your efforts! Actually there is also issue with wrapping text inside a cell which on my experience also causes errors in a pixel size of cell. And as you stated fort size may be different. I think I should think of these issues too, but it is really hard to do as users can use any font of their choice and each font has it's own heigth. I think it should me mentioned, and may be other actions of user may influence too. Anyways the original Q was about the issue with border sizes, I think another Q should be made for other issues.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about processing the cell range as the image processing by increasing the base canvas size of the cell range? Specifically, when the cells "A1:A5" including various edited fonts and borders and wrappers are exported, the cell image is put on a large canvas including a border at most outer cells. And, the image outside of the outer border is removed. By this, the cell image can be retrieved from various situations. I'm not sure whether this can be achieved using only Google Apps Script. But, I would like to try.

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike! I Thought of another solution on the front JS side. I could test the final PDF I create: how much pages it has. If the number of pages is 1 - preceed. If the number of pages is 2 - fetch the URL and increase the size a bit. if the number of pags is > 2 -- at least double the size.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. I apologize for this. In your current situation, you could achieve your expected result by resolving several issues in the comments. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, I'm sorry, the reason you did not understand is because I did not mention, I'm creatind a PDF URL from that range, and then convert it into an image. The whole solution I use is available here: https://max-makhrov.medium.com/google-sheets-script-range-2-image-5824577f4fc3. As I have a built PDF on the JS side, I can also see the number of pages it has. My goal was to create a PDF that fits a single page, or create a canves with multiple PDF pages and render an image. The JS code I use is placed here: https://github.com/Max-Makhrov/range2image/blob/main/demo/Index.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `create a PDF that fits a single page`, in this case, are there the maximum sizes of width and height? For example, when 10,000 rows are exported, I'm worried about this limitation.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike! As ususal you're correct. For now I've manually tested this and found the limit of ~1100 rows of data. I think this amout of rows should be reasonably enough for most of user cases. But my tests were also about rendering the page into PNG. I did not test the PDF page limits, they may appear even bigger!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand your reply. And also, I agree with `For now I've manually tested this and found the limit of ~1100 rows of data. I think this amout of rows should be reasonably enough for most of user cases.`. About multiple pages, for example, how about merging each page as an image? But, in this case, the image height might be longer. For example, as the 1st version, how about targeting only one page? I think that even for one page, there are several problems that should be resolved in our discussions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247112/discussion-between-max-makhrov-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export the range as an image using Google Apps Script and Javascript.
- In order to achieve this, in this question, you want to calculate the row height of the selected cell range.

### Issue and workaround:

As our discussions in the comment, in the current stage, when the correct row height of the cell range is trying to be obtained, there are several problems as follows.

- When the border is used for the cells, it seems that the row height + the border size is different from the exported result. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129310159_73204237)
- Pixel size might not be changed linearly with the value of row height and border size. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129315115_73204237)
- When I tested the cell size including the borders, I thought that the tendency of change of size might be different between height and width. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129375393_73204237)
- When the row height is the default (21 from getRowHeight) and the text font size in the cell is increased, the value retrieved by getRowHeight is not changed from 21. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129375393_73204237)
- `There is also issue with wrapping text inside a cell which on my experience also causes errors in a pixel size of cell.` [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129378643_73204237)
- From your question, when the selected cell range is large, the number of pages is more than 2. In this case, all pages cannot be correctly merged as an image.

From the above situation, I'm worried that obtaining the correct size of the selected cells might be difficult. So, I proposed to process this as image processing. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204237/google-sheets-how-to-get-the-real-range-size-in-pixels#comment129378735_73204237) I thought that when this process is run with the image processing, the above issues might be able to be avoided.

But, unfortunately, in order to process this as image processing, there is no built-in method in Google Apps Script. But, fortunately, in your situation, it seems that Javascript can be used in a dialog. So, I created a Javascript library for achieving this process as the image processing. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/CropImageByBorder_js)

When this Javascript library is used, the sample demonstration is as follows.

[image]

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare a Spreadsheet.

Please create a new Spreadsheet and put several values to the cells.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
function getActiveRange_(ss, borderColor) {
  const space = 5;

  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  const obj = { startRow: range.getRow(), startCol: range.getColumn(), endRow: range.getLastRow(), endCol: range.getLastColumn() };
  const temp = sheet.copyTo(ss);
  const r = temp.getDataRange();
  r.copyTo(r, { contentsOnly: true });
  temp.insertRowAfter(obj.endRow).insertRowBefore(obj.startRow).insertColumnAfter(obj.endCol).insertColumnBefore(obj.startCol);
  obj.startRow += 1;
  obj.endRow += 1;
  obj.startCol += 1;
  obj.endCol += 1;
  temp.setRowHeight(obj.startRow - 1, space).setColumnWidth(obj.startCol - 1, space).setRowHeight(obj.endRow + 1, space).setColumnWidth(obj.endCol + 1, space);

  const maxRow = temp.getMaxRows();
  const maxCol = temp.getMaxColumns();
  if (obj.startRow + 1 < maxRow) {
    temp.deleteRows(obj.endRow + 2, maxRow - (obj.endRow + 1));
  }
  if (obj.startCol + 1 < maxCol) {
    temp.deleteColumns(obj.endCol + 2, maxCol - (obj.endCol + 1));
  }
  if (obj.startRow - 1 > 1) {
    temp.deleteRows(1, obj.startRow - 2);
  }
  if (obj.startCol - 1 > 1) {
    temp.deleteColumns(1, obj.startCol - 2);
  }

  const mRow = temp.getMaxRows();
  const mCol = temp.getMaxColumns();
  const clearRanges = [[1, 1, mRow], [1, obj.endCol, mRow], [1, 1, 1, mCol], [obj.endRow, 1, 1, mCol]];
  temp.getRangeList(clearRanges.map(r => temp.getRange(...r).getA1Notation())).clear();

  temp.getRange(1, 1, 1, mCol).setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, borderColor, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  temp.getRange(mRow, 1, 1, mCol).setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, borderColor, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return temp;
}

function getPDF_(ss, temp) {
  const url = ss.getUrl().replace(/\/edit.*$/, '')
    + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    // + '&size=20x20' // If you want to increase the size of one page, please use this. But, when the page size is increased, the process time becomes long. Please be careful about this.
    + '&scale=2'
    + '&top_margin=0.05'
    + '&bottom_margin=0'
    + '&left_margin=0.05'
    + '&right_margin=0'
    + '&sheetnames=false'
    + '&printtitle=false'
    + '&pagenum=UNDEFINED'
    + 'horizontal_alignment=LEFT'
    + '&gridlines=false'
    + "&fmcmd=12"
    + '&fzr=FALSE'
    + '&gid=' + temp.getSheetId();
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  return "data:application/pdf;base64," + Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent());
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const temp = getActiveRange_(ss, "#000000");
  const base64 = getPDF_(ss, temp);
  let htmltext = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().getContent();
  htmltext = htmltext.replace(/IMPORT_PDF_URL/m, base64);
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplate(htmltext).evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'sample');
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}

function saveFile(data) {
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), MimeType.PNG, "sample.png");
  return DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side: `index.gs`

Here, I used a Javascript library of [CropImageByBorder_js](https://github.com/tanaikech/CropImageByBorder_js) for processing this as the image processing.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.11.174/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/CropImageByBorder_js@latest/cropImageByBorder_js.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
  var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.11.174/pdf.worker.min.js';
  const base64 = 'IMPORT_PDF_URL'; //Loaading the PDF from URL
  const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
  pdfjsLib.getDocument(base64).promise.then(pdf => {
    const {numPages} = pdf;
    if (numPages > 1) {
      throw new Error("Sorry. In the current stage, this sample script can be used for one page of PDF data. So, please change the selected range to smaller.")
    }
    pdf.getPage(1).then(page => {
      const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: 2});
      cvs.height = viewport.height;
      cvs.width = viewport.width;
      const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
      const renderContext = { canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport };
      page.render(renderContext).promise.then(async function() {
        const obj = { borderColor: "#000000", base64Data: cvs.toDataURL() };
        const base64 = await CropImageByBorder.getInnerImage(obj).catch(err => console.log(err));
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = base64;
        img.onload = function () {
          cvs.width = img.naturalWidth;
          cvs.height = img.naturalHeight;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(id => console.log(id)).saveFile(base64.split(",").pop());
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

#### 3. Testing

When you test this script, please select the cells and run `main()`. By this, the selected cells are exported as an image (PNG) to the root folder as follows. In this case, you can see the above demonstration.

[image]

#### 4. Flow.

In this sample script, the following flow is used.

1. Manually select the cells, and run the script of `main()`.
2. At the script, the selected cells enclosed by the single row and column are created as a temporal sheet.
3. Export the temporal sheet as a PDF data as base64. Here, the PDF data is sent to Javascript side.
4. Convert 1st page of PDF data to an image using PDF.js.
5. Cropping the selected cells using CropImageByBorder_js, and return the result image to Google Apps Script side.
6. Save the image as a file to Google Drive.

### LIMITATION:

- **In this sample script, it supposes that the selected range is put on one PDF page. So, when you select a large range, when the number of PDF pages is more than 2, unfortunately, this script cannot be used. So, please be careful about this.**
- And also, in this case, Javascript is used on a dialog. So, when you use this sample script, it is required to open the Spreadsheet and select the cells and run the script.

### Note:

- In your showing script, in order to use a created PDF data with PDF.js, the Spreadsheet is required to be publicly shared. But, in the case of PDF.js, it seems that the data URL can be directly used. So in this sample script, the created PDF is used as the data URL (base64). By this, it is not required to publicly share the Spreadsheet.
- Updated on January 25, 2024.

### References:

- [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)
- [CropImageByBorder_js](https://github.com/tanaikech/CropImageByBorder_js)